# Arrow key and mouse navigation for AJAX Live search

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am using the below code for autocomplete feature in webpage. The problem is that I am not able to navigate through the suggestion using mouse pointer. But if up/down key is pressed once after the list item refreshed mouse pointer navigation is working fine.

1. Could you please suggest the code change to make the mouse pointer and keyboard navigation work like the navigation in html select option?
2. How can I improve the scrolling of suggestion list using up/down key?

HTML:

```
<div class="field-wrap">

<input type="text" id="college"  placeholder="College Name" required autocomplete="off"/>
<ul id="college_list"></ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.field-wrap ul {
    width: 93%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    border: 1px solid #3498DB;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background: #0F0F0F;
    list-style: none;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

.field-wrap ul li {
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid grey;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
}


#college_list {
    display: none;
}

.selected {
    background: #2980B9;
}
```

Javascript:

```
// livesearch : this function will be executed every time we change the text
function livesearch() {
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $.trim($('#college').val());
    if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'livesearch.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {keyword:keyword},
            success:function(data){
                $('#college_list').show();
                $('#college_list').html(data);
            }   
        });

    } else {
        $('#college_list').hide();
    }
}

// set_item : this function will be executed when we select an item
function set_item(item) {

    // change input value
    $('#college').val(item);

    // after selecting an item, update list item and hide proposition list 
    var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
    var keyword = $('#college').val();
        if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'livesearch.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {keyword:keyword},
                success:function(data){
                    $('#college_list').hide();
                    $('#college_list').html(data);
                }
            });
        }

}

// Display or hide list based on focus in search box

$('#college').focus(function() {

    livesearch();

    $(document).bind('focusin.college click.college',function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('#college, #college').length) return;
        $(document).unbind('#college');
        $('#college_list').fadeOut('medium');
    });

});


// Disable default behaviour of form submit when enter is pressed for livesearch text box

$('#college').bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13 ) { e.preventDefault(); }
});


// Livesearch list or navigate and select a list item based on keyup events 

$('#college').keyup(function(e)
{   

    var $listItems = $('.field-wrap li');
    var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;


// Search text pattern in database if key pressed is not up/down/enter 

    if ( key != 40 && key != 38 && key != 13 ) livesearch();


    $listItems.removeClass('selected');

// navigate or select list item based on up/down/enter key pressed if list is visible

    if($('#college_list').is(':visible')) {

        var menu = $('#college_list');
        var height = $selected.outerHeight(); //Height of <li>
        var top = menu.scrollTop(); //Current top of scroll window
        var menuHeight = menu[0].scrollHeight; //Full height of <ul>

        if ( key == 40 ) // Down key
        {
            if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child') ) {
                $current = $listItems.eq(0);
                menu.scrollTop(0);
            }
            else {
                $current = $selected.next();
                menu.scrollTop(top + height);
            }   

            $current.addClass('selected');          
        }

        if ( key == 38 ) // Up key
        {
            if ( ! $selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child') ) {
                $current = $listItems.last();   
                menu.scrollTop(menuHeight + height);
            }
            else {
                $current = $selected.prev();
                menu.scrollTop(top - height);
            }
            $current.addClass('selected');
        }

        if ( key == 13 ) // Enter key
        {    
        $current = $selected;

        // If selected text in list is not blank change the text in search box else hide list and retain entered text in search box

            if($current.addClass('selected').text()!='') {
                set_item( $current.addClass('selected').text() );
            }
            else {
                $('#college_list').fadeOut('medium');
            }
        }

    }

        $('#college_list li').mousemove(function() {
            $('.field-wrap li').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        });
});
```

Livesearch.php:

```
<?php
// PDO connect *********
function connect() {
    return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=expertreaders', 'root', '', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
}

$pdo = connect();
$keyword = '%'.$_POST['keyword'].'%';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE college_name LIKE (:keyword) ORDER BY college_name ASC";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$list = $query->fetchAll();
foreach ($list as $rs) {
    // put in bold the written text
    $college_name = preg_replace('/' . preg_quote($_POST['keyword'], "/") . '/i', "<b><font color=green>\$0</font></b>", $rs['college_name']);
    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", $rs['college_name']).'\')">'.$college_name.'</li>';
}

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The mouse navigation working after the key press because you defined the `mousemove` event handler inside the `keyup` event. And for dynamically created html contents like this use always `$(document).bind` or `$(document).on` like functions as event handler.
There are duplicate event handlers in your code. Is it necessory?
Eg:

```
$('#college').bind('keypress keydown keyup', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13 ) { e.preventDefault(); }
});


// Livesearch list or navigate and select a list item based on keyup events 

$('#college').keyup(function(e)
{   

    var $listItems = $('.field-wrap li');
    var key = e.keyCode,
        $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
        $current;
```

Use a single handler and apply conditions.
like

```
if(e.keyCode == 13 ) { //do some stuff 
}
else {
//Do something else
}
```

Try my answer. Pardon me if you get anything wrong